# Can I track unexpected lack of changes using change feeds, cosmos db and azure functions?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to understand [change feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed) in Azure. I see I can trigger an event when something changes in cosmos db. This is useful. However, in some situations, I expect a document to be changed after a while. A question should have a status change that it has been answered. After a while an order should have a status change "confirmed" and a problem should have status change "resolved" or should a have priority change (to "low"). It is useful to trigger an event when such a change is happening for a certain document. However, it is even more useful to trigger an event when such a change after a (specified) while (like 1 hour) does not happen. A problem needs to be resolved after a while, an order needs to be confirmed after while etc. Can I use change feeds and azure functions for that too? Or do I need something different? It is great that I can visualize changes ([for example in power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cosmos-db/changefeed-ecommerce-solution)) once they happen after a while but I am also interested in visualizing changes that do **not** occur after a while when they are expected to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving that with Change Feed doesn't sound possible, because as you describe it, Change Feed is reacting based on operations/events that happen.

In your case it sounds as if you needed an agent that needs to be running every X amount of time (maybe an Azure Functions with a TimerTrigger?) and executes a query to find items with X state that have not been modified in the past Y pre-defined interval (possibly the time interval associated with the TimerTrigger). This could be done by checking the [`_ts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/documents) field of the state documents or your own timestamp field, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214165/5641598.

If your goal is to just deploy it on a dashboard, you could query using Power BI too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need too much time precision *(the Change Feed notifications are usually delayed by a few seconds)* for this task, the Azure CosmosDB Change Feed could be easily used as a solution, but it would require some extra work from the Microsoft team to also support capturing deletion TTL expiration events.

A potential solution, if the Change Feed were to capture such TTL expiration events, would be: whenever you insert *(or in your use case: change priority of)* a document for which you want to monitor lack of changes, you also insert another document *(possibly in another collection)* that acts as a timer, specifying a TTL of 1h.

You would delete the timer document manually or by consuming the Change Feed for changes, in case a change actually happened.

You could also easily consume from the Change Feed the TTL expiration event and assert that if the TTL expired then there were no changes in the specified time window.

If you'd like this feature, you should consider voting issues such as this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/402 and feature requests such as this one: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/14603412-execute-a-procedure-when-ttl-expires, which would make the Change Feed a perfect fit for scenarios such as yours. Sadly it is not available yet :(

**TL;DR No, the Change Feed as it stands would not be a right fit for your use case. It would need some extra functionalities that are planned but not implemented yet.**

***PS. In case you'd like to know more about the Change Feed and its main use cases anyways, [you can check out this article of mine](https://medium.com/@domenicosibilio/azure-cosmos-db-change-feed-a-zero-downtime-data-migration-story-99c4521f7159) :)***